# Break If Statement in While loop without breaking the while loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Ok, So Im creating a while loop for multiple accordions in php. I marked up some php code that ALMOST works. The problem I am having is that I had to nest five different IF statements in a while loop for the five different accordions. The If statements contain the content to be in the accordion. The content is a list of songs in a particular album. What I need to happen is for the If statement containing the content for one accordion to break, but still continue with the original while statement and do this for each accordion. Here is my PHP Code.

```
if ($result)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
               {
                   echo '<div class="col-small-6 col-med-6 col-lg-4 albumContainer">';
                   echo '<img src=' . $row['Album_Art'] . 'alt="">';           
                   echo '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">';
                   echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
                   echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
                   echo '<h2 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' . $row['direction'] . '>' . $row['Title'] . '</a></h2></div><div id=' . $row['destination'] . ' class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"> <ol>';
                   if($result1)
                   {
                        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {                               
                            echo '<li>' . $row1['Name'] . '</li>';                              
                        }; 
                    }; 
                    if($result2)
                    {
                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row2['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    };
                    if($result3)
                    {
                        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row3['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    };
                    if($result4)
                    {
                        while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row4['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    };
                    if($result5)
                    {
                        while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row5['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    };
                    if($result6)
                    {
                        while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row6['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    };
                    echo '</ol>';
                    echo '<h3>available at:</h3><a href=' . $row['Location'] . '>iTunes</a>
                    <a href=' . $row['Location2'] . '>Amazon</a>
                    <a href=' . $row['Location3'] . '>United Interests</a></div>';
                    echo '</div></div></div></div>';
                }
                    mysqli_free_result ($result); 
        }
            else 
            {
                echo '<p class="error">The current users could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
                echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
            } 
            mysqli_close($dbcon); 
            ?>
```

Any insights on how to make this work for me would be greatly appreciated. I cant use Jquery for the accordion because of how the code was previously structured.

Comment: If you write break in inner while loops, then it wont break the outer while loop.

Comment: Try 'continue;' --

if ( $var ) {
  continue;
}

Comment: All that repeated code smells like you should read about procedures (called "functions" in PHP). If you then feed the right query to your DB, it should only return the stuff you really need that you then format using such a function. Otherwise, if you have the data in an array of arrays and want to retrieve just one column from that, use `array_map`. That said, it's not really clear what jump (in the sense of program flow) you want to make, your description is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

use `continue` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.
>
> Note: Note that in PHP the switch statement is considered a looping
>   structure for the purposes of continue.

also, you should probably use a switch instrad of multiple `if` conditions